# How to save search results when reloading page or clicking "back" button with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a web application with a search page that loads information from the backend. When the user searches for something specific, the relevant data appear. However, when the user reloads the page, the search results are deleted. Also, if the user click on a specific search results, a new page loads a more detailed view about this search. When you click the back button of the browser, the search results are lost again. How do I save the search results when the page is refreshed, or when the user wants to go back to search results?

I would appreciate an AngularJS based solution, since this is the framework I am using. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ui-router or ngRoute for routing. It seems like you don't use it because you said when a user clicks on back button, results are lost. If you used routing, the page would not refresh and results couldn't be lost if you had them saved in a scope.

For persistent storage after refresh I suggest using [window session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

In your app, you can inject $window service into your controller/service or whatever you want and then use it like this:

```
$window.sessionStorage["myVar"] = 'this will be here even after refresh';
```

In case a user refreshes the page, you can retrieve the contents of the variable like so:

```
var myVar = $window.sessionStorage["myVar"];
```

Comment: I think this is not very angular, Paresh's solution seems better.

Comment: @GrantLay I think this is just personal preference, not about being angular or not angular. Peresh answer actually doesn't show anything angular at all. He only provides an external link to a library, but doesn't show how to use it with particular focus on the question. Also the question is not only about persistent storage, but also about routing, even though not directly. But like I said, answers are pretty similar, if Paresh provided solution how to use the ngStorage library here, then yes, his answer could be more angular.

Comment: @emil.c apologies, reading the mozilla link I thought you were using the javascript window object directly. Of course the $window (not window) you use in your example is a valid angular way to interact with the sessionStorage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage for that.

```
localStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Please look for more advance features

[ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage)